# Can't figure out how to return an array

Tags: java

> **[Find all pairs with a given sum](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-all-pairs-whose-sum-is-x5808/1#)**
>
> Given two unsorted arrays A of size N and B of size M of distinct elements, the task is to find all pairs from both arrays whose sum is equal to X.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class pair  {  
    long first, second;  
    public pair(long first, long second)  
    {  
        this.first = first;  
        this.second = second;  
    }  
}

class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        while(t-->0)
        {
            StringTokenizer stt = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            
            long N = Long.parseLong(stt.nextToken());
            long M = Long.parseLong(stt.nextToken());
            long X = Long.parseLong(stt.nextToken());
            long A[] = new long[(int)(N)];
            long B[] = new long[(int)(M)];
            
            
            String inputLine[] = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                A[i] = Long.parseLong(inputLine[i]);
            }
            String inputLine1[] = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                B[i] = Long.parseLong(inputLine1[i]);
            }
            
            
            Solution obj = new Solution();
            pair [] answer = obj.allPairs(A, B, N, M, X);
            int sz = answer.length;
            
            if(sz==0)
            System.out.println(-1);
            else{
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
                    if(i<sz-1)
                    output.append(answer[i].first +" "+ answer[i].second + ", ");
                    else
                    output.append(answer[i].first +" "+ answer[i].second);
                    
                }
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
// } Driver Code Ends


//User function Template for Java

/*
class pair  {  
    long first, second;  
    public pair(long first, long second)  
    {  
        this.first = first;  
        this.second = second;  
    }  
}
*/

class Solution {
    public pair[] allPairs( long A[], long B[], long N, long M, long X) {
        
        //MY CODE STARTS FROM HERE
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(long i : A){
            set.add(i);
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            if(set.contains(X-B[i])){
                list.add(X-B[i]);
                list.add(B[i]);
            }
        }
        long arr[] = new long[list.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arr[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
prog.java:101: error: incompatible types: long[] cannot be converted to pair[]
        return arr;
               ^
1 error
```

How can I correctly return the answer?

Comment: `long arr[]` which you are returning is not what the method expects to be returned `public pair[] allPairs` - I asked for an Orange and you give me an Apple

Comment: You need to decide whether the method is supposed to return an array of pairs or an array of longs, and code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get into the answer, it is very important to use descriptive variable names when writing your code. They might make sense to you, but people like me who aren't you, and possible even you in the future, have a hard time understanding what A, B, M, N, etc mean.

The reason you are getting this error is because your function `allPairs()` has a return type of pair[], but you're trying to return long[]. It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do because of your variable names, but it seems like when you find a result that you desire you are adding the first and second results separately into an array of longs, which also undermines the point of your pair class. Here's an idea of what it should probably look like instead:

```
    class Solution {
        public pair[] allPairs( long A[], long B[], long N, long M, long X) {
      
            //MY CODE STARTS FROM HERE
            ArrayList<pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
            HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
            for(long i : A){
            set.add(i);
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
            if(set.contains(X-B[i])){
                list.add(new pair(X-B[i], B[i]));
            }
        }
        pair arr[] = new pair[list.size()];
        arr = list.toArray(arr);
        return list.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't put those variable names or datatype. They were already given by GeeksForGeeks. I just wrote the function. You can see that I wrote "My code starts from here" - that's where I started coding from. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in your define method return type is pairs, but  actually return a long[], it must be compile error

you should modify the Solution as follow

```
class Solution {
public pair[] allPairs( long A[], long B[], long N, long M, long X) {

    //MY CODE STARTS FROM HERE
    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(long i : A){
        set.add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        if(set.contains(X-B[i])){
            list.add(X-B[i]);
            list.add(B[i]);
        }
    }
    pair arr[] = new pair[list.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i]=new pair(X-B[i], B[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}